# processing compile works in linux, fails in windows

Tags: linux, windows, processing

In a grading perl script, code is copied into a temp directory:

```
grading2/temp/tmp
```

within this directory, we are compiling code.  For the processing language, the compiler is processing-java

In order to compile, we create a directory named a, and then rename the program to a.pde inside a, resulting in:

```
grading2/temp/tmp/a
```

which contains a.pde

from the tmp directory, we type

```
processing-java --sketch=a --output=test --build
```

This works on linux, and is successfully implemented in the script that runs and tests all the code.
However, on windows, the same command results in the error:

a is not found.

The code is in a directory:

```
d:\Course\Java_TA\grading2\xxyyyj\temp\tmp
```